# amount calculation in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a payment amount of 2628.46. This payment should be used to pay off, in turn, three components listed in columns BZ, CA and CB. So, first I subtract the April Principal from the May payment. If there are sufficient funds in the May payment, then I set the value in cell CE to zero (i.e. the principal is fully covered). With the remainder, I try to pay the "Accrued" value. If there are sufficient funds in the May payment to pay both the Principal and the "Accrued" value, then I set cell CF to zero (i.e. the "Accrued value is also fully covered). I then repeat the same step with the Penalty column. If the May payment has sufficient funds to cover all three components carried forward from April, then I can set the May penalty to 0. If not, I must set the May penalty to the amount that is yet to be covered.

In this example, I need formulas that will show 0 in cells CE and CF (because  the payment 2628.46 is sufficient to cover both 597.31 and 1182.31), and a formula that will show 941.28 in cell CG (because this is the amount that would not be covered by the payment).

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! Why have you not entered the formula: for CE, =CD3247-BZ3247? For CF, =CD3247-CA3247? For CG, =CD3247-CA3247?

Comment: If you try its 2628.46-597.31 it will give u amount of -2031.15 but there debt should be 0 then from rest of amount witch is 2031.15 we nedd to take 1182.31 so acurred shoudl be 0 then the rest of amunt witchis 848.84 need to be taken from 1790.12 so reesult shoud be 941.28. 
But problem is than on cels where we calculate first and second it canto show -amount because then total calculation will mismatch

Comment: Could you please explain more about "debt should be 0", "acurred shoudl be 0"? Should they be filled in some sepcific cells? Thx

Comment: Hi Emily like shown in photo
We have a customer with loan (bank loan) and due to delay of payment clits get penalty as usual. so i this case we have x number of customer who pay monthly fess of loans.
The payment in May is Registered in Cell (CD) with amount of 2628.46 now if you look in cels BZ, CA, CB, we have for same customer amounts that he owns to bank so after pay we first need to calculate amount of Principal Prill witch is on cell BZ and the result should be put in cell Principal May (CE) then from same amount of payment witch was

Comment: 2628 we need to take Accured debt witch is in this case 1182 as in Cell (CA) and result should be put in cell Acured May or (CF) and also then from same amount we need to take of Acured Penalty amound and result to be shown in Cell (CG),  so i would like if there si any posibility to calculate somehow formula for the 3 cels.
In this case result on cells CE, CF should be 0 but problem is how to calculate because if you go with rregullar formula like you canot get 0 you will get - left amount witch then make mismatch in all table :S

Comment: Please put all the details in the question using the [Edit] button, rather than in the comments. Use the punctuation generously - it improves readability.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly, I believe you can use the formulas shown below:

[image]

i.e.

```
=IF(C2-G2<0,0,C2-G2)
=IF((C2+D2)-G2<0,0,(C2+D2)-G2)
=IF((C2+D2+E2)-G2<0,0,(C2+D2+E2)-G2)
```

Please edit the cell references to fit your table.

In each case, we test if subtracting the May payment from the sum of the items to be covered will cause the result to be less than zero. If it is, those items are covered by the payment, so the result is zero. If that subtraction is greater than zero, then the responsibilities are greater than the payment, and we show the remainder in the cell.

Comment: A milion times thnxxxxx its so amazing its workingg

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MIN()` formulas to get the smaller of two (or more) values.

For example:

in column CE: `=MIN(CD3247,BZ3247)`

in column CF: `=MIN(CD3247-CE3247,CA3247)`

in column CG: `=MIN(CD3247-CE3247-CF3247,CB3247)`

You may have to change `,` to `;` for international version of excel...